# What in-game user interfaces are available?

Tags: gui

I'm wondering what options are available for in-game interface libraries (not OS-level interfaces) and what are your opinions about them?

Please put only one library per answer and follow this template.

- Name
- Link to website
- Cost
- License (if free or open source)
- General summary / Opinion

Comment: possible duplicate of [What C++ GUI library can you suggest?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/what-c-gui-library-can-you-suggest)

Comment: When I started this question the other question about gui has only OS-level gui libraries answers.

Answer (score 2):

The OGRE3d engine uses [CEGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It's FOSS, supports scripting from lua, predefined layouts can be created in XML, supports most of the basic widgets you would need *(see [cegui.org.uk](http://cegui.org.uk/docs/current/fal_baseclass_ref.html) for more documentation)*.

You can also find lots of UI demos using CEGUI on YouTube.

Comment: I really wish there was a CEGUI lite.  The library is so heavy, and uses some real heavy 3rd party stuff as well, xerces etc.  Not to mention it's obsessed with dynamic loading everything.

Answer (score 1):

I've been meaning to try out [libRocket.com](http://librocket.com/), though I haven't done so yet. Seems, it allows to lay out the interface using a subset of HTML and CSS, which could be pretty efficient.

It's free for download (and comes with source), but as far as I know they use a custom licence, so not sure about what possible caveats there might be.

Comment: libRocket has recently gone fully open source under the MIT license with no licensing fees.