# GUI for DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, gui

I'm looking for a GUI library built on top of DirectX- preferably 9, but I can also do 11. I've looked at stuff like DXUT, but it's way too much for me- I'm only needing some UI controls which I would rather not write (and debug) myself, and their need to keep a C-compatible API is definitely a big downside. I'd rather look at UI libs that are designed to be integrated into an existing DirectX-based system, rather than forming the basis of a system. Any recommendations?

Edit:

I guess that nobody has heard of a DirectX GUI written by someone who has heard of the basics of object-orientation? The purpose of not using DXUT was because using their API was worse than writing my own, and the documentation that starts with `namespace::type::GetInstance()` is *not* qualifying as "better than DXUT".

Comment: Potential duplicate http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/what-c-gui-library-can-you-suggest

Comment: I believe WFP uses DirectX to render its content.

Comment: Not even remotely a duplicate, as I'm rendering with DirectX, not looking for a general-purpose lib.

Comment: @Nate Bross: If you have a native interface to it, I'm all ears.

Comment: Totally a duplicate. CEGUI supports both DirectX and OpenGL: http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Features DXUT also doesn't look anything remotely like a GUI library, more like a GLUT or GLFW type of thing.

Comment: tiny file dialogs on sourceforge is a single C C++ cross-platform file offering many modal dialogs. It has no init, no main loop, no linking and no include.

Answer (score 6):

[CEGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Answer (score 3):

[MyGUI](http://mygui.info/) is very good.  It works with DirectX as well as OpenGL and [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/MyGUI).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, there's not much available for DirectX, which I think is a great shame. The closest thing I've found is AntTweakBar which (unless you only want the GUI to act as an interface to tweak colours/behaviours/graphics/etc) isn't very fully featured.

Of course I haven't used it very much, so it may have more features to it but check it out at: http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools:anttweakbar

Answer (score 2):

Check out [GWEN](http://gwen.facepunchstudios.com/) from the maker of Garry's Mod.

Comment: It looks like GWEN is supports OpenGL as well.  Mention this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/good-gui-for-opengl and you may get the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will get you what you're looking for, but here's a MSDN document on [WPF and Win32 Interoperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx). The section "Hosting WPF Content in a Microsoft Win32 Window" may be of the most interest to you. Also, from the first link: [Walkthrough: Hosting WPF in Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744829.aspx).

While I've never done this, it may be able to get you the benifits you're looking for without having to do too much wheel re-inventing.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi/ C++Builder with FireMonkey

FireMonkey is a cross platform (opengl for mac and directX for windows) gui library which look similar to native controls as possible.

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/firemonkey;

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi

Answer (score 0):

There is also [librocket](http://librocket.com/) which allows one to implement the render part by yourself. So you will be able to adapt it to DirectX, wich is already done within one of the examples.

Furthermore it's XHTML1.0 and CSS2.0 based and allows you to build your ui as you would build a websie, with some constraints tho.