# Anyone have a game UI recommendation?

Tags: c++, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What C++ GUI library can you suggest?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/what-c-gui-library-can-you-suggest)

I am creating a simple 2 dimensional GUI for an RPG game. It will be pretty simple and will contain a few windows a chat box. Does anyone have any suggestions for UI code to use?

Comment: What language and/or libraries are you using?

Comment: I am coding in C++ and am looking for something crass platform if possible. I am also using SDL so if there is something there that allows me to create a nice GUI, let me know.

Comment: tiny file dialogs on sourceforge is a single C C++ cross-platform file offering many modal dialogs. It has no init, no main loop, no linking and no include.

Answer (score 4):

For really, really, really simple GUIs, I recommend rolling your own IMGUI library. If all you need are buttons and sliders, it's dead simple. If you need anything more, I recommend looking at some other GUI libraries, though.

- http://iki.fi/sol/imgui - my step by step IMGUI tutorial
- http://iki.fi/sol/files/Assembly07_IMGUI.pdf - IMGUI seminar slides by me and Jetro Lauha
- http://silverspaceship.com/inner/imgui/ - another implementation
- http://mollyrocket.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=10 - discussion on Molly Rocket website
- http://mollyrocket.com/861 - the original lecture on IMGUIs

Answer (score 2):

I have had a positive experience with [Guichan](http://guichan.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/About). It has an SDL back-end (as well as others) and a good set of basic widgets.

Some highlights:

- Widgets are easy to extend, which makes it great if you're building a simple RPG GUI. I was able to extend widgets for my game such that new ones could be created entirely by the scripting language -- it was great!
- It is not multi-threaded, which could be seen as a positive and a negative. It's up to the implementer to decide when (and in which thread) things are rendered.
- It allows components to communicate through the use of an [Event](http://guichan.sourceforge.net/api/0.8.1/classgcn_1_1Event.html) system.

If you haven't already, check it out. I have used it in the past and plan on using it for my next project.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/download/we-recommend) team recommends both [Crazy Eddie's GUI System](http://www.cegui.org.uk/) and [MyGui](http://mygui.info/), so they might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

There are Flash based GUI systems too.  There's the open-source projects [GameSWF](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/gameswf.html) and [Hikari](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=41999) for .  There are commercial products too - [Scaleform](http://www.scaleform.com/)